# Search results thumbnails different size

Tags: search, post-thumbnails, thumbnails

Seems that according to the nature of my theme, whenever I do a search query and a result from my *Projects* section appears, the pictures appear huge and even break the footer! Whereas if I do a search query that finds something from my *Blog* section, they appear fine.
Example here:
Projects section search result: https://unsafebutsound.com/?s=of+earth
Blog section search result: https://unsafebutsound.com/?s=goat

What can I do to push post results that go under *Projects* section to appear as neat as the ones appearing as a post result for *Blog* section?

Kindly advise!
So thankful!!!

Answer (score 0):

This is down to  difference in the classes output by different types of content in your theme's search page.

The CSS of your theme restricts the width of Posts to 50% of the screen with this rule

```
.blog-area .type-post.size-2x1 {
    width: 50%;
}
```

But for your project content, there is no 'type-post' or 'size-2x1' classes so the same constraint is not there. Images will be much wider.

I can't tell you why these classes are coming out differently as thats something specific to your Wordpress theme. It's possible that to solve this properly you will need to change the code of the Search page template as well as adding some more CSS, specific to the needs of your search page.

Comment: Thanks a lot @t2pe , I thought so!

Comment: Any clue how to fix that in steps?

Comment: Open the site back up again and I'll have another look for you.